# How to write logs to a file using Log4j and Storm Framework?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, apache-storm

I am having bit of an issue in logging to a file using log4j in storm .

Before submitting my topology , i.e in my main method I wrote some log statements and configured the logger using :

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(myLog4jProperties)
```

- Now when I run my topology using my **executable jar** in eclipse -
  its working fine and log files are being created as supposed.
  OR
  When i run my executable jar using "java -jar MyJarFile
  someOtherOptions", i can see log4j being configured and the files are
  formed correctly and logging is done on both files and console (as
  defined in my log4j.properties)
- **BUT** when i run the same jar using "storm jar MyJarFile MyMainClass someOtherOptions" it is not being able to create and log
  into any of the files except on console.

I am talking about the logs I am printing **BEFORE** submitting my topology.

Is there any way to log my statements in a file while using storm ? I am **not** bound to use **org.apache.log4j**.

Comment: You are using a local cluster as a jar exec? When you use "storm jar ..." you are using the cluster mode. So did you check the file storm.log.properties on your storm install dir / log4j in your server ? When you submit a topology in cluster mode, storm is already running and writing logs, maybe you can't overwrite log4j at runtime, so modifying the storm log4j file before should work in all cases.

Comment: @zenbeni I am actually running in local_mode. 
I can't find any  log4j related properties in storm install directory. I am using apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating.

Answer (score 4):

The storm framework uses its own logging.  Your logs most likely will end up in the logs dir where storm is installed({Storm DIR}/logs).  You can find the storm log properties in {Storm DIR}/logback/cluster.xml.  It uses logback not log4j

Comment: This file defines properties for files in apache-storm-incubating-0.9.2.jar. Sure I can change the properties for that. But I want to change the logging properties for MyJarFile.jar. cluster.xml won't affect its logging. And also I am able to define properties for logs which are printed AFTER submitting my topology, i.e on supervisor nodes. I just can't get the logs (which are present in MyJarFile.jar) to print in a file BEFORE submitting my topology.

Comment: how can i make use of log4j over slf4j jar?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using SLF4J for your logging within storm. You probably could get LOG4J working but you will have additional setup to do on each node in the cluster. Since storm does this for you already, I don't really see the point.

In your project, include these maven dependencies (slf4j-simple for your unit tests!):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, inside your topologies/spouts/bolts you just get the Logger:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySpout.class);
```

In my environment, anything INFO and above is logged to file and, more importantly, **visible in the Storm UI**. You just need to click on your spout/bolt and then click on the port number to go to the log viewer page.

If you want to get to the actual files then you can gather them off of each node (mine are in `/var/log/storm/`).

Comment: So when u say " get to the actual files" are u saying about worker-<port>.log files which by default goes into $STORM_HOME/logs directory . or u mean to say u configured ur log4j file with path as /var/log/storm ? 

Also , is there any way for Storm to not use Cluster.xml and use ur log file which u sent in the jar u deployed to the cluster.

Comment: @AnkurGarg I meant the worker-port.log files. Anytime you call LOG.info or above inside your topology it will be logged to those worker logs and visible in the Storm UI.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for replying Kit :)

Comment: my problem is I have about 10 applications running on master. Every times I want to grab log file for an application I have to go to each node , search for port in order to get worker-xxx.log. Is there any way to configure the name of log for each application ?