# Logs not getting printed while running topology on Apache Storm Cluster

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, apache-storm

Log file is getting created and logs are getting written into it.But,when I run it on the cluster it writes only the log messages which are specified in the main method.It does not write the logs messages specified in the bolts and spouts.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,error,R

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.R.File= /home/ubuntu/Documents/logsInfer/ConsumerStorm.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %r [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.Con=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Con.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Con.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %r [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Comment: How is your `log4j.properties` file included with your deployment?

Comment: Also, you may want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679963/how-to-write-logs-to-a-file-using-log4j-and-storm-framework

Comment: Thanks .I know storm writes the log in storm/logs/ .I wanted to write the logs in the file location specified by me in my log4j.properties. Any way to achieve that ?

Comment: Its more than where they write the logs. Storm uses logback, not log4j, so unless your supervisor nodes somehow have log4j on their classpath, your log4j.properties settings will have no effect. Much like the post I referenced says, I would recommend using slf4j over logback (which is what the Storm framework itself uses).